# Logstash to Keep Two Databases Synced - Cannot Access %{document_id}

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using Logstash to keep my Elasticsearch synced with an HBase, via an API.

Here is my configuration file:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["<elasticsearch_ip>"]
    index => "<some_name>"
    type => "<some_name>"
    query => '{ "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must_not": [
          {"term": {"synced": true}}
        ]
      }
    } }'
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "synced" => true }
  }
}

output {
  if [type] == "<some_name>" {
    http {
      format=>"json"
      http_method=>"post"
      url=>"http://<api-ip>/<endpoint>"
    }
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => [<elasticsearch-ip>]
      action => "update"
      index => "<some_name>"
      document_type => "<some_name>"
      document_id => "%{document_id}"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to add a `synced` field to the document so that I do not index them twice in HBase. The problem is that `%{document_id}` is not converted to the actual `_id` of the document. I think there is not such field, as I try to add it to the body of the document with `add_field => { "document_id" => "%{document_id}" }` and it did not get converted. I have also tried `%{_id}` and `%{id}` but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** Have I heard of Watcher? Well, of course, and I actually implemented this using it at first. But have you heard of its price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the [`docinfo` flag](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-inputs-elasticsearch-docinfo) to true in your `elasticsearch` input

```
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["<elasticsearch_ip>"]
    index => "<some_name>"
    type => "<some_name>"
    docinfo => true
    query => '{ "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must_not": [
          {"term": {"synced": true}}
        ]
      }
    } }'
  }
```

And then you can access the document id in your output with `[@metadata][_id]`

```
elasticsearch {
  hosts => [<elasticsearch-ip>]
  action => "update"
  index => "<some_name>"
  document_type => "<some_name>"
  document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"  <-- change this
}
```